# git push to remote branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-push, git-remote

Folks,

I had cloned a repo. I created a branch out of it to work on a feature by issuing the following command:

`git branch fix78`

then I worked on that branch by

`git checkout fix78`

I continued to make commits to this local branch. Now I wanted to push this to the repo and hence I issued the following command:

`git push origin master:fix78`

I viewed the repo from a web browser and saw that a new branch called fix78 was created on the repo. But it did not have any of my commits that I had made.

What am I doing wrong here? This is what I am trying to achieve:

There is a repo(master(trunk in the SVN lingo)), now when I am working on a feature I want to create a local branch of it and then I also want to check in this branch to the repo(so that other team members can see what I am working on), then I want my local branch to be in sync with this remote branch that I create.

Any help/feedback would be totally awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 61):

`git push origin master:fix78` pushes the local master to a remote branch called fix78. You wanted to push the local branch fix78, which has the same syntax but without the `master:`

You can fix it by doing `git push origin :fix78` to delete the remote branch and then `git push origin fix78` to push your local branch to the remote repo.

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot, I totally understood the difference between git push origin master:fix78 and git push origin :fix78

Answer (score 52):

The push command has the form of

```
git push remote_name source_ref:destination_ref
```

All you need to do to correct your error is

```
git push origin +fix78:fix78
```

The plus indicates that you don't care about that branch potentially losing history as the previous push was an error.

Alternate syntax is

```
git push -f origin fix78
```

if you omit the destination, it's implied that it's the same name. If tracking is set up to a particular branch on the remote it will go to that one. Deleting branches has 2 syntaxes, the old:

```
git push -f origin :fix78
```

and

```
git push --delete origin fix78
```

The first is read as "push nothing into fix78" which deletes it.

One trick is that if you specify `.` as the remote name, it implies the current repo as the remote. This is useful for updating a local branch without having to check it out:

```
git push . origin/master:master
```

will update master without having to checkout master.

Hope this helps