# How to make a remote branch from a local branch in Git?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I was working on a branch. But one of the contributors deleted the remote version of the branch. So, I now have a local copy of the code but no remote branch to push to. How do I recreate the remote version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git push to remote branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279082/git-push-to-remote-branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check to see if the old remote is still in your list:

```
git remote -v
```

If it is, and you want to delete it, you do:

```
git remote rm [remote-name]
```

... for example.

Now create a new "remote" with the URL of the new repository host:

```
git remote add origin [https://github.com/user/repo.git]
```

Then to push your local branches up to it:

```
git push --all -u
```

(Replace all the stuff in brackets with the correct info for your repository.)