# Pushing local branch to remote branch in git

Tags: git

I am trying to push my local branch 'opt' to remote branch origin/tech.
My head points to the remote branch origin/tech.
I am using the following command

```
git push -u origin/tech opt
```

But its failing with the error

```
fatal: 'origin/tech' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: could not read from the remote repository
```

The remote branch origin/tech has been confirmed to exist by doing git branch -r.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git push to remote branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279082/git-push-to-remote-branch)

Comment: git branch -r lists branches. If it outputs ```origin/tech```, it means that ```origin``` is a remote while ```tech``` is a branch on that remote.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `origin/tech` is a remote ***branch***, not a remote

`git branch -r` lists branches. If it outputs `origin/tech`, it means that `origin` is a remote while `tech` is a branch on that remote.

So you should do

```
git push -u origin opt:tech
```

to push your local branch opt to the remote branch tech.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

In particular take a look at the examples on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
git push origin opt:tech
```

`origin` is your name of your remote. `opt:tech` has to be understand as `local_branch:remote_branch`.

Answer (score 0):

The below error could be caused if either the branch name doesn't match or the remote url is not configured

> fatal: 'origin/tech' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: could not read from the remote repository

1. **Fix when branch doesn't exist:**

   ```
    git push -u origin opt:tech
   ```
2. **When remote url is not configured:**

   Check if the remote url is added using *git remote -v* and if not then use the below to add a remote:

   ```
    git remote add origin <remote url>
   ```